# Resolve path to unit test using gatsby-plugin-root-import

Tags: javascript, path, gatsby

When running my app, everything is running fine as expected. However, if I run a test using jest, the test can't make the connection of the path in my gatsby config file. Below is a hiearchy of what I am running into.

gatsby-config:

```
...

{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-root-import",
      options: {
        reducers: path.join(__dirname, "src/reducers"),
        sagas: path.join(__dirname, "src/sagas"),
        web: path.join(__dirname, "src/web"),
        test: path.join(__dirname, "src/web"), <-------- test cases don't live on the root
      },
    },

....
```

[image]

Test Error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'web/components/graphs/line-graph' from 'src/web/components/card/index.js'

    Require stack:
      src/web/components/card/index.js
      src/web/components/card/test/index.test.js

      1 | import React from "react"
      2 | import { string, array } from "prop-types"
    > 3 | import LineGraph from "web/components/graphs/line-graph"
```